# wss 3.0 Webpart Disappears after couple of days of operation

Tags: web-part, wss-3.0

I have custom wss 3.0 webpart installed in my wss site. This webpart is deployed to many servers. Performance is very positive and stable all across other servers. Recently i have encountered a weird problem in one server. After couple of days of operation Web part just disappears from webpart zone. I have tried deactivating and reactivating back, redeployed the webpart but it hasnt helped.
Has anyone encountered with this situation ever. Seeking for your suggestions.
Thank You

Comment: I'm leaning towards a user is doing it, but it's hard to prove in WSS. When viewing the web part maintenance page, can you open some of the closed web parts? You may have to use SharePoint designer to reopen them.

Comment: I ask to help determine if the web part is somehow corrupted or not.

Comment: David how would we find out if the webpart is corrupted or not.

Comment: using SharePoint Designer, you can edit the page and then go to the properties of a web part to open it back up on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disallow closing the web part by clearing the "Allow close" checkbox in web part properties. Details [here](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Why-you-should-not-allow-users-to-Close-Web-Parts.aspx).

Comment: I applied those changes, lets see what happens. I will keep you posted. Thank You

Comment: I'm curios to see if this will work. if an admin is doing it, won't their permissions override this checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure a user has not just deleted the webpart from the page, or has closed it?

Comment: Thank You for your responce Colin. I asked my site administrators they are sure that nobody took it off or has closed it. When i go to advanced webpart gallery i see those webparts in closed web part section. I dont know how to deal with this.

Comment: So it appears that someone has closed the web part, as it appears in the closed web parts section. See my answer below/above.

Comment: Seeing as a page in a library is nothing more than a listitem, any user with edit rights on that item will be allowed to close the webpart (edit the page). SO you need to either make the page / webpart personalizable, or disallow closing like Jussi suggested)

Comment: I made change on Monday, Today is Friday. Webpart is still intact. I took all other Site Collection Administrators off except one guy.

Comment: Good to hear. The problem with webparts is, anyone with edit rights on the library (or the item) can close or delete them. And when the page / webparts does not allow personalization, the change affects everybody. Planning who should be able to do what is an essential part of your governance strategy. P.S.If my answer led you to the solution, please accept is as the answer.